# Remove "A-Z." from every list entry if it's there in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, list, list-comprehension

Sorry this might be an easy question but struggling to find a best way. I have list like below, and am wanting to remove all parts that contain any letter and a . afterwards.

So I want to transform this.

```
list = ['A. Person', 'B. House', 'H. Normal', 'My House', 'Hello World']
```

And transform it in to this.

```
list = ['Person', 'House', 'Normal', 'My House', 'Hello World']
```

What would be the easiest way to do this? I initially thought about a `startswith("")` but couldn't think what to put in it seeing as all the beginning letters are different. Maybe regex is the best answer?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes. Regex is probably the simplest - how did it go, when you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming there is only every one period, you could split by ". " and take the last element.

```
l = ['A. Person', 'B. House', 'H. Normal', 'My House', 'Hello World']
l = [i.split(". ")[-1] for i in l]
print(l)
>>> ['Person', 'House', 'Normal', 'My House', 'Hello World']
```

Comment: If there are multiple such instances (e.g. `G. H. Normal`), specifying `.split('. ', maxsplit = 1)` might help.

Comment: What would happen if a list entry was, for example, 'A.Person' ?

Comment: @DarkKnight If that was a possibility you could split by `.` and strip the white space. I'm just going off the info OP gave. The "correct" answer really depends on OPs specific data set.

Answer (score 3):

Try this ?

```
original_list = ['A. Person', 'B. House', 'H. Normal', 'My House', 'Hello World']

pattern = r'^[A-Z]\.\s*'
filtered_list = [re.sub(pattern, '', item) for item in original_list]

print(filtered_list)
```

Comment: You probably don't want the leading caret in the pattern. Consider what would happen if the list contained 'Mr A. Person'

Comment: To handle cases like 'Mr A Person', you can use this  pattern = r'(?:[A-Z][a-z]* )?[A-Z]\.'

Answer (score 0):

If the format is always like `A. Person` then you can simply iterate over the list like this

```py
letters = ["A.", "B.", ...]

for entry in list:
  for letter in letters:
    if letter in entry:
      entry = entry.replace(letter, "")
```

Answer (score 0):

Data changed to allow for other possibilities:

```
import re

p = re.compile(r'[A-Z]\.\s*')

_list = ['Mr A. P. Person', 'B.House', 'H. Normal ', 'My House', 'Hello World']

print(*(p.sub('', e) for e in _list), sep='\n')
```

**Output:**

```
Mr Person
House
Normal 
My House
Hello World
```